# Multiplicative structure on algebraic K-theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Using Quillen's $+$-construction, it is relatively easy to see that the algebraic K-theory of $R$, $K_*(R)$, admits a graded commutative product $$K_i(R)\otimes K_j(R) \to K_{i+j}(R).$$ The proof essentially boils down to showing that $BGL(R)^+$ is an H-group.

We also know that the $+$-construction agrees with Waldhausen's $S$-construction in this case.

My question is: Is there a way to construct this product on $K$-theory using Waldhausen's $S$-construction?

I know that this is done for commutative ring spectra in EKMM, so I guess I could apply their method to $HR$. But there is probably a much simpler way to see this, without having to pass by stable homotopy theory.

Answer (score 2):

See Waldhausen's paper in the Annals, Generalized Free Products, section 9, for a construction of products using the Q construction.  The same thing works for the S construction, the idea being that the tensor product of two filtered modules is a bifiltered module; I don't know a good reference for that at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that. I guess it will be easier to go from $Q$ to $S$, than from $+$ to $S$. So that can be helpful.

Comment: You can also see section 6 of my paper with Gillet on the loop space of the Q-construction, where we do products, too.  See http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~dan/cv.xhtml#loops